# why my htaccess for Angular reload no working

Tags: angular, .htaccess, ubuntu, server, subdirectory

1. error on Reload
2. the backoffice  is a subdir

- [www.example.com/backoffice](http://www.example.com/backoffice)  (It works)
- [www.example.com/backoffice/products](http://www.example.com/backoffice/products) (It works)
- [www.example.com/backoffice/products/new](http://www.example.com/backoffice/products/new)   (Error white page)
- [www.example.com/backoffice/products/edit/1](http://www.example.com/backoffice/products/edit/1)  (Error white page)

I trie: this is code actually is my .htaccess

```
# Angular app
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
# Rule
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

# APP-FOLDER-NAME
RewriteRule ^(.*) /backoffice/index.html [NC,L]
```

I think the error is somewhere .htaccess

Comment: Well, what does your http server's error log file say? That is where you can simply read what is wrong with your configuration file.

Comment: no error.log in apache , the page in network work request. in console error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Comment: An apache http server _always_ writes an error log file (except you implemented some really exotic setup). But the error message you post indicate that there is an issue within your application logic, not within your http server setup. Please add _the full_ error message to the question above (there is an "edit" button below it ...). The message _including_ the information where in what file.